# Can we change the x-axis in an ascending order while giving a constraint

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted a bar graph, in which I want to display the labels in descending order, while my label-'five'should always be in the last.

[image]

Above shown is my original graph generated using the below code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# x-coordinates of left sides of bars  
left = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

# heights of bars 
height = [10, 24, 36, 40, 5] 

# labels for bars 
tick_label = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'] 

# plotting a bar chart 
plt.bar(left, height, tick_label = tick_label, 
        width = 0.8, color = ['red', 'green']) 

# naming the x-axis 
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
# naming the y-axis 
plt.ylabel('y - axis') 
# plot title 
plt.title('My bar chart!') 

# function to show 
# function to show the plot 
plt.show
```

Output:

I want the x-axis to be displayed in `descending order from one to four` and my `fifth label` should always be in the last.
()

Comment: Descenidng order from four to one?  You mean?

Comment: Yes, Depending on data, my one to four labels can act in such a way that should be in descending order @ScottBoston, and the fifth label should always be in the last.

Comment: Is okay to import numpy or pandas?

Comment: Yes, anything can be used or imported @ScottBoston

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need to just plot the elements of the list (except the last one) in descending order. This can be done by sorting all **but** the last element of the list and then appending the last element to the reverse sorted list. The reverse sorting (descending order) can be done by first sorting the list and then reversing it using `[::-1]`. If this is not what you want, drop a comment below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

left = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
height = [10, 24, 36, 40, 5] 
tick_label = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'] 

height_plot = sorted(height[:-1])[::-1] + height[-1:]

plt.bar(left, height_plot, tick_label = tick_label, 
        width = 0.8, color = ['red', 'green']) 

plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
plt.ylabel('y - axis') 
plt.title('My bar chart!') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

In case you want also to change the x-axis tick-labels, do the following

```
height_plot = sorted(height[:-1])[::-1] + height[-1:]
new_labels = tick_label[:-1][::-1] + tick_label[-1:]

plt.bar(left, height_plot, tick_label = new_labels, 
        width = 0.8, color = ['red', 'green'])
```

[image]

Comment: Suppose,  if I want label three to be in the last, and the remaining ones to be sorted in ascending or descending order, can we ?

Comment: @pylearner: In principle you can. The trick there will be to first find the index of `three` and then create another list which does not include three wither by using indexing (like in my answer) and adding different sublists OR by using a list comprehension to create a list which excludes `three`. Then sort ascending/descending this list (without `three`) and proceed as I did.